# filter objects with two nested levels in a query with Realm

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, realm, subquery

I have a model like this:

```
class CalendarEvent: Object, Mappable {


dynamic var exId = ""
@objc dynamic var title:String = ""
@objc dynamic var desc:String = ""
dynamic var fullDate = Date()
dynamic var date = ""
dynamic var time = ""
dynamic var location = ""
dynamic var subcategory:Subcategory?
dynamic var update = false
var participants = List<Participant>()
}

class Category:Object, Mappable{
dynamic var exId = ""
@objc dynamic var name="";
var subcategories = List<Subcategory>()
}

class Subcategory:Object, Mappable{
dynamic var exId = ""
dynamic var name = ""
let category = LinkingObjects(fromType: Category.self, property: "subcategories")
dynamic var active:Bool = true
dynamic var update = false
}
```

I need to know which CalendarEvents are from a category, when is from a subcategory I can do:

```
var results = realm.objects(CalendarEvent.self)
results = results.filter("ANY subcategory.exId == %@", subcategory!.exId)
```

But when I need to obtain the CalendarEvents filtered by category I don´t know how to do it. I looked after the solution but didn´t find anywhere. Please help!

Comment: The use case is a little unclear; there's a relationship between Category and Subcategory and inverse relationship from Subcategory back to Category. But then there's a unidirectional relationship between CalendarEvent and Subcategory i.e. a CalendarEvent can have one Subcategory. Why? If you want a Category to have multiple calendar events why not have a one to many relationship between Category and CalendarEvent or have a one to one between SubCategory and CalendarEvent.

Comment: For example categories can be :  meetings, special events.... And examples of subcategories from meetings can be financial, administrative....

And example of calendarEvent is a meeting of type financial which takes place on 19 March at 12:00 AM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the record, I found the solution. It´s easy, you need to subdivide in queries and chain then using "IN". For example:

```
let resultsSubcategory = realm.objects(Subcategory.self).filter("ANY category.exId == %@", category?.exId)
        results = results.filter("subcategory IN %@", resultsSubcategory)
```

Comment: I removed my answer because I misunderstood the question. It wasn't clear the exId on the objects are duplicated which is how you wanted to do the filtering. Go it now and gave you an upvote.

Comment: Yes exId is the nomenclature for each id that comes from the server (exterior). Anyway, thanks for your attention